# Apache gives 403: Forbidden despite permissions (seemingly) being correct

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, permissions

I'm running Apache as `www-data`, I have `chown`'d `/usr/local/apache/htdocs` (the document root) to this user + it's group, yet when I try to visit it, Apache gives me a 403.

Is there anything I'm missing here?

I'm running a fresh Apache installed from the latest stable tarball (2.4.4) that was configured with:

```
./configure --enable-vhost-alias --enable-proxy --enable-mimemagic --enable-rewrite --enable-so --with-included-apr
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was due to a way that 2.4 does access control vs 2.2, in my vhost directives I needed to change:

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

To:

```
Require all granted
```

See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html#run-time